# Can't make this Func<T,T> to work

Tags: c#, .net, func

I have a cache method which is

```
 public TReturn Get<TParam, TReturn>(string cacheId, Func<TParam, TReturn> getItemCallback, TParam argument)
        where TReturn : class
        where TParam : class
    {
        TReturn item = (TReturn)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId);
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback(argument);
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheId, item);
        }
        return item;
    }
```

and i try to use it and it seem ive got no luck here... normally it should work. I am using it this way.

```
 public List<LookupParameter> GetAllLookupEntries(string tableContext)
 {
     return _cacheProvider.Get<string,List<LookupParameter>>("", 
         _lookupTableRepository.GetAllLookupEntries(tableContext), "");
 }
```

It say it can't convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<Pyrosphere.Providers.LookupParameter>` to `System.Func<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<Pyrosphere.Providers.LookupParameter>>`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your passing a `List<string>` as the second parameter and it's expecting a `Func<string, List<string>>`.  Try passing the second argument as a lambda expression

```
return _cacheProvider.Get<string,List<LookupParameter>>(
  "", 
  arg => _lookupTableRepository.GetAllLookupEntries(arg), 
  tableContext);
```

Also it may be a bit simpler if you change your `Get` function to not take an argument.  The argument is provided to the `Get` method and then immediately passed back to the delegate with nothing else done in between.  So the callsite could be much simpler by having it handle the argument directly. For example

```
public TReturn Get<TReturn>(string cacheId, Func<TReturn> getItemCallback)
    where TReturn : class
{
    TReturn item = (TReturn)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId);
    if (item == null)
    {
        item = getItemCallback();
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheId, item);
    }
    return item;
}


return _cacheProvider.Get<List<LookupParameter>>(
  "", 
  ()=> _lookupTableRepository.GetAllLookupEntries(tableContext));
```

Comment: Nice solution! +1 It worked and since this was my first attempt at first i am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the GetAllLookupEntries function and passing the return value (presumably a List) where the argument type is expecting a callback function.

Try using a lambda to make a clearer distinction between passing a function as an argument versus passing the result of a function call:

```
return _cacheProvider.Get<string, List<LookupParameter>>("", 
    r => _lookupTableRepository.GetAllLookupEntries(r), "");
```

Comment: You've also gave a nice solution! since it respond directly to my requirement you gonna get +1 too but i prefered JaredPar solution because this was my original way to do things (with only a type and not two type). But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What does `_lookupTableRepository.GetAllLookupEntries(tableContext)` return?

Your method's second parameter is of type `Func<TParam, TReturn>`. Make sure that's what your `GetAllLookupEntries` returns.

Comment: Good try but there no example or real solution to my problem here your simply tell me what i was already knowing.. but since i never worke with func<> was a bit harder to figure it out.